# Wordpress: How to keep a widget-sidebar open by default?

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar, area

Problem: I have 2 sidebars (widget-areas). In the admininistration-backend sidebar 1 is always open, but sidebar 2 is closed by default, when I navigate to "Design -> Widgets". See this screenshot:
[image: the second sidebar "Teaser Sidebar" is closed by default (red area)]

Question: Is there a way to configure to keep the second sidebar open by default?

Wordpress version 3.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widgets in the WordPress admin dashboard are controlled by jQuery UI specifically the opening and closing is controlled by jQuery UI Collapsable.

When you make adjustment like opening and closing collapsable items the last state is always stored in a cookie and the state should be the same when you come back to the page.  The same is true for the collapsable state for the menu items on the left sidebar.

If it is not working for you most likely you dont have javascript enabled on your browser or a plugin is causing a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I have javascript enabled and also cookies are enabled, so this seems to be a plugin-problem. Thank you for your help.